# Phrase to describe a fix when you are not sure of the actual issue

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for a phrase you would use when you have made a fix to something but you are not sure what the problem is in the first place.

For example I pushed out a software fix today to address a problem but I was unable to find out what the problem was. What would you call that fix?

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Phrase to describe a fix that doesn't address the underlying issue?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346431/phrase-to-describe-a-fix-that-doesnt-address-the-underlying-issue) ////  And [work-around is given in this duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/349197/is-there-a-noun-for-addressing-a-problem-but-not-quite-a-solution/349224#349224).

Comment: Yep, [band-aid solution](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/band-aid-solution) would be the best answer to your question.

Comment: He "stackoverflowed it". :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the "fix" will allow the system to carry on working by avoiding the underlying "real" problem then this is known as a "**work around**".

E.G. you do not call a sub-system that crashes, but, instead return a "not available" message, while you work out how to fix the more complex underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the lack of addressing the underlying, root cause means that your fix is a **stopgap** measure.

> something that serves as a temporary expedient

The implication is that you've not address the real issue, although it's not limited to cases where you don't know. For instance, a more complete fix may take weeks, but a temporary, stopgap fix will alleviate the problem from an end-user perspective. It's a commonly used term in software development.

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stopgap)